# How to static link EDK II library into application in Visual Studio 2008 tool chain

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, makefile, uefi, efi

I have EDK II application and library in package and it works fine when I compile it with library source codes. Now I want to remove the library source codes and link that library with application through .lib file.

I remove library source codes references from my application project and now I'm getting this message while I'm building this application:

```
DemoApp.lib(DemoApp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TestFunction
fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals.
```

To solve this, in DSC documentation they mention that I need to add library instance into make file as shown in below:

```
LIBS = $(LIBS) $(LIB_DIR)/$(LibInstanceName)
```

Problem is how can I add this entry into make file / EDK II build system?

I'm using VS2008 as my tool chain.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made it by adding `[BuildOptions]` entry into Application INF.

In that section I add parameters to Microsoft Linker to get the .lib file from library path:

```
MSFT:DEBUG_VS2008x86_X64_SLINK_FLAGS = /LIBPATH:"C:\TestApp\DEBUG_VS2008x86\X64\TestAppPkg\Library\TestLib\TestLib\OUTPUT" "TestLib.lib"
```